# Bone rotation applied twice

Tags: transforms, bones

[image]

In this image, the top bone is rotated by 45 degrees, but the model is deformed like there was a rotation of 90 degrees. This also happens for translation and scaling.

For each vertex, the sum of the weights is one.

What am I missing? The code for skinning is inspired by the second piece of code here: [Rigged mesh](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Armatures)

Thanks

Comment: check to make sure you don't have 2 armature modifiers

Comment: You're right! Post this as the answer so I can accept it! Now I just need to find a way to make sure it only creates one modifier instead of two.

Comment: So basically, my error was in my indentation in my python script... the modifier was created in a loop instead of just at the end.

Comment: okay, I don't know python, but i'll just say what I did before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by multiple armature modifiers on the mesh. Delete one to get better results. Notice that for each number of armature modifiers on the mesh, it (the mesh) is bent again by the same angle.

[image]