# Rigify moves twice as far as mesh?

Tags: animation, rigify

I'm building a modular animatable child for a school project.

I can't figure out why my rig does this, but every pose ball and limb piece moves twice as far as the rig which makes it much harder to animate, every tutorial i look up has the rig follow the model exactly, can anyone please help?

The .blend:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mmsc5r77fivbs6/ChidlerfileAlpha2.blend?dl=0

Comment: Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33169/bone-rotation-applied-twice

Answer (score 0):

looks like your helpers are children are of the rig and are therefore also affected, my understanding is they should remain static since their referenced by bones. With only your last layer visible go to your outliner, set to only visible layers, select any mesh withing the rig heirarchy, now change your outliner view to same types, select all (A),right click the mesh and chose 'select', hit alt+P in the 3D view to un-parent. Now go back to your first layer and the rig should behave properly.

Comment: I couldn't follow exactly what you meant but i believe you mean that i accidentally parented the WGT rig, which was causing the rigify to scale it as well, thus double scaling the mesh, which once i unparented all the WGT bits it is working correctly so thank you!